# What EF does when updating via EntityState.Modified?

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

Suppose a regular Controller and an ApiController with their context's `ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` are set to `true` and `false` respectively.

There is a way to update entities in EF setting it's state to `EntityState.Modified`.

```
_context.Entry(newEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

When the entity is loaded on the `Controller` everything works as expected. As for the `ApiController` having my navigation properties to `null` - because of disabling the proxies for that instance of the context.

What will happen if I change any property or set it's state to `Modified` and save the changes?
What will entity framework do with those `null` navigation properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you are using independent or foreign key associations.

For independent associations - these are associations that don't have the foreign key as a property in your model, but only the navigation property - nothing will happen with the navigation properties and foreign key values in the database if you set the state to `Modified`. They remain unchanged because the generated UPDATE statement won't include a change of the FK column value. It's by the way also the case if the navigation property is *not* `null`. Setting the entity state to `Modified` does not affect navigation properties, only scalar properties.

If you have foreign key associations - associations that have the foreign key as a property in your model - setting the state to `Modified` will mark the foreign key property as `Modified` because it is a scalar property. As a result the current FK property value will be written to the database and possibly change a relationship there, even if the navigation property is `null`.

Comment: I have foreign key associations indeed, so the navigation properties **will be assigned** to `null` if I update via `Entity.State = EntityState = Modified` right? Is there a way to achieve this, any pointer will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Esteban: "*Is there a way to achieve this*": Do you mean that you actually **want** that the reference is nulled out in the database? In this case for foreign key associations you should have a nullable foreign key property (like `int?`). If this property is `null` and you set the state to `Modified` the `null` will be written into the DB.

Comment: No I don't want my navigation properties to be set to null. Thats what I needed to read: `you should have a nullable foreign key property (like int?). If this property is null and you set the state to Modified the null will be written into the DB.` Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Stumbled across this because I am trying to update a navigation property (for a many to many) in an EDIT action on a controller.  I am setting the new navigation property values but they are not being updated - now I see why!  So how am I supposed to update them, to reflect a change in the many to many relationship?

Comment: @GilShalit: Here is an example how to update a many-to-many relationship: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16594412/270591